# Why I cannot create alias in Mixpanel?

Tags: php, alias, mixpanel

In Mixpanel I have an user who have the automatic **distinct_id** `145dsfds-sdfsdf` *(example)*. I want to create an **alias** for that user to `1234`

*My PHP code:*

```
require ('mixpanel/mixpanel.php');
$original_id = '145dsfds-sdfsdf'; // Example original
$uid = 1234;
$token = '2j34j3j4j3j'; // Token of my project on Mixpanel

$_mp = new Mixpanel($token);
$_mp->createAlias($original_id,  $uid);
$_mp->people->set($uid, array(
    'uid'   => $uid
));
```

After run, I go into Mixpanel and filter people with id `1234` and retrieve no result. But if we visualize the details of user `145dsfds-sdfsdf`, the property `uid` have value `1234`.

*I don't understand what's happening.*

Answer (score 0):

The root of the issue here is that Mixpanel's alias function is designed to remap the `uid` to the `original_id` but not the reverse.

Essentially, if an alias is successfully made, the distinct_id you see in live-view will be a `original_id`, not the `uid`.

The alias function allows you to tie pre-authentication events to post-authentication events without needing to edit the events already stored in Mixpanel (events are immutable once they are in a project).